# Plot while changing different parameters matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, parameters

I've written the following code for pricing options in matlab:

```
    function call=CallBinomial(S,E,T,r,sigma)

S=100;  
E=90; 
T=2; 
r=0.03; 
sigma=0.2;

n=50;
dt=T/n;1
u=exp(sigma*sqrt(dt)+(r+0.5*sigma^2)*dt); d=1/u;
disf=exp(-r*dt);  
p=0.5; 

X=zeros(n+1,n+1);
for k=1:(n+1) 
    X(n+1,k)=max(S*u^(k-1)*d^(n-k+1)-E,0); 
end
for m=n:-1:1
    for k=1:m 
        X(m,k)=disf*( p*X(m+1,k+1) + (1-p)*X(m+1,k) );
    end
end
call=X(1,1)
```

I want to plot a graph of the changing value of the call as I vary different parameters S, r, sigma but i'm unsure of how to do this.

Comment: A for loop and plot?

Comment: I've tried doing this (starting the for loop before setting the parameters), but my plot keeps coming up blank

Comment: So, the way I see it, there is a problem in a different part of the code, not in the one you show..... So why did you show this one and not the problematic one?

Comment: But this code runs and gives me a value for the call option, I just can't plot it as I change the parameters

Comment: This code runs== there is no problem with this code == there is no reason to ask about this code. **Add the problematic code**. Please, read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simle example where you can change the parameters to plot *inside* a for loop:

```
for i = 1:.1:2
    plot(i,i); % plot different things
    axis([0 3 0 3]); % forces a constant size of window
    pause(.2); % pauses before the next plot
end
```